# Can child elements be aligned top or bottom in Figma's auto layout?

Tags: layout, figma

I have a horizontal auto layout within which there are three elements:

1. Icon
2. Text
3. Another Icon

I made this [screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUp56.jpg) that shows what I did. I'd like the text to be aligned top or bottom, but it remains centered.

Is it possible to do this in Figma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new auto layout update, you can do it. Example image from Figma blog is below.

More info is on [Figma Blog for Auto Layout](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040451373-Create-dynamic-designs-with-Auto-Layout#Alignment)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The issue was that the parent had a fixed padding of 22 both ways vertically. After I remove that (set 0 in the middle field in the screen capture below) and set a fixed height on the parent, I can align the text element wherever I want:

[image: Figma Auto Layout]